# Requesting a function from another file in a class not working

Tags: c++

I have 2 .cpp files called "FactoringProgram.cpp" and "FactoringProgram2nd.cpp", also 1 header file called "FactoringProgram.h". I've already tried searching for this problem on StackOverflow and a couple other sites and haven't found a solution that worked for me. When I try to run this command: "g++ FactoringProgram.cpp FactoringProgram2nd.cpp" I get this error:

> *FactoringProgram.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: FactoringProgram.cpp:8:11: error: request for member ‘InitialMessage’
>   in ‘Problem1’, which is of non-class type ‘Factoring()’
>
>   Problem1.InitialMessage();*

The code for "FactoringProgram.h" is:

```
#ifndef FactoringProgram_h
#define FactoringProgram_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class Factoring
{
private:
    int m_FirstCoefficent;
    char m_FirstOperator;
    int m_SecondCoefficent;
    char m_SecondOperator;
    int m_3rdExpression;
public:
    Factoring();

    int InitialMessage();
};

#endif
```

FactoringProgram.cpp code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "FactoringProgramH.h"

int main()
{
    Factoring Problem1();
    Problem1.InitialMessage();
    return 0;
}
```

FactoringProgram2nd.cpp code:

```
#include "FactoringProgramH.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

    Factoring::Factoring(int FirstCoefficent=0, char FirstOperator='+',
     int SecondCoefficent=1, char SecondOperator='+', int 3rdExpression=1)
        : m_FirstCoefficent(FirstCoefficen), m_FirstOperator(FirstOperator),
    m_SecondCoefficent(SecondCoefficent), m_SecondOperator(SecondOperator),
    m_3rdExpression(3rdExpression);
    {

    }

int Factoring::InitialMessage()
{
    std::cout << "Ok right now your expression is looking like: "
        << FirstCoefficent << "x^2 " << FirstOperator << " " << SecondCoefficent
        << " x" << SecondOperator << " " << 3rdExpression;
}
```

Comment: Your code suffers from [the most vexing parse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Use `Factoring Problem1;`.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your `include` statements? `FactoringProgramH.h` instead of `FactoringProgram.h`.

Comment: Please remove _**sublimetext3**_ tag, it is not relevant to the question

Comment: @eneski This is where you edit/suggest an edit.

Comment: You are absolutely right @PasserBy but I tried many times and question is waiting for approval of another edit for long time

Comment: Read up on *linking*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several small errors. Here is a version that works (you can compare and see what I had to change). A summary of the changes are:

- default parameter values should be in the header file (*.h);
- you cannot start variable/argument names with numbers;
- `int InitialMessage()` doesn't return anything, so I changed it to `void InitialMessage()`;
- when you initialize fields in a constructor, the last field cannot end with a semi-colon;
- fixed the [most vexing parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) (per @RSahu comment) in `main.cpp`.

**FactoringProgram.h**

```
#ifndef FactoringProgram_h
#define FactoringProgram_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class Factoring
{
private:
    int m_FirstCoefficent;
    char m_FirstOperator;
    int m_SecondCoefficent;
    char m_SecondOperator;
    int m_3rdExpression;

public:
    Factoring(int FirstCoefficent = 0, char FirstOperator = '+',
              int SecondCoefficent = 1, char SecondOperator = '+', int thirdExpression = 1);

    void InitialMessage();
};

#endif
```

**FactoringProgram.cpp**

```
#include "FactoringProgram.h"

Factoring::Factoring(int firstCoefficent, char firstOperator, int SecondCoefficent, char SecondOperator, int thirdExpression) :
        m_FirstCoefficent(firstCoefficent),
        m_FirstOperator(firstOperator),
        m_SecondCoefficent(SecondCoefficent),
        m_SecondOperator(SecondOperator),
        m_3rdExpression(thirdExpression)
{}

void Factoring::InitialMessage()
{
    std::cout << "Ok right now your expression is looking like: "
              << m_FirstCoefficent << "x^2 " << m_FirstOperator << " " << m_SecondCoefficent
              << " x" << m_SecondOperator << " " << m_3rdExpression;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "FactoringProgram.h"

int main()
{
    Factoring Problem1;
    Problem1.InitialMessage();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To this error substitute:

```
Factoring Problem1();
```

by:

```
Factoring Problem1 = Factoring();
```

The problem is that the compiler is interpreting this line as a function declaration rather than a variable declaration. AS mentioned in the comments, this is known as the most vexing parser problem.

Obs: The code you posted contain many more minor errors.

Comment: Why not `Factoring Problem1;`?

Comment: Works just fine as well. The way I wrote it is a bit more generic as it would also work if you needed to pass parameters to the constructor.

Comment: If you need to pass parameters to the constructors then `Factoring Problem1( 1,2,3 );` - you never need (or should) write it the way you did. And it is not "more generic".

Comment: Read the example at [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) and you will see that you can have a problem with that notation.

Comment: No, you can't. You don't understand the most vexing parse. For example, you should always say `string s( "foobar" );` and not `string s = string( "foobar" );`.

Comment: So you are saying that you can never have a problem using `TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());` ? I agree with you that `Factoring Problem1;` is a simpler way to write it for this question, but there is nothing wrong with my solution.

Comment: Your solution is not wrong, but it is unnecessarily complicated, and not the way that C++ code (as opposed to Java and C#) is written.  And what, in the context fof this question is `TimeKeeper `? But don't tell me - I won't be replying to any more of your comments.

Answer (score -1):

You should define `Factoring()` without params and I used headers in FactoringProgram.h

FactoringProgram.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class Factoring
{
private:
    int m_FirstCoefficent;
    char m_FirstOperator;
    int m_SecondCoefficent;
    char m_SecondOperator;
    int m_3rdExpression;
public:
    Factoring();
    Factoring(int,char,int,char,int);

    int InitialMessage();
};

#endif
```

FactoringProgram.cpp

```
#include "FactoringProgram.h"

int main()
{
    Factoring Problem1 = Factoring();
    Problem1.InitialMessage();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

FactoringProgram2nd.cpp

```
#include "FactoringProgram.h"

Factoring::Factoring()
{
    *this = Factoring(0, '+', 1, '+', 1);

}
Factoring::Factoring(int FirstCoefficent = 0, char FirstOperator = '+',int SecondCoefficent = 1, char SecondOperator = '+', int _3rdExpression = 1) : m_FirstCoefficent(FirstCoefficent), m_FirstOperator(FirstOperator),m_SecondCoefficent(SecondCoefficent), m_SecondOperator(SecondOperator),m_3rdExpression(_3rdExpression)
{

}

int Factoring::InitialMessage()
{
    std::cout << "Ok right now your expression is looking like: "
        << m_FirstCoefficent << "x^2 " << m_FirstOperator << " " << m_SecondCoefficent
        << " x" << m_SecondOperator << " " << m_3rdExpression;
    return 0;
}
```